Why error in the "synchronous" part of promise/async function is handled differently
Compare these 2 snippets:
try {
    console.log('start')
    const test = (() => {
        console.log('inside')
        const a = null;
        a.c = 1
    })()
    console.log('end')
} catch (error) {
    console.log('nvmnghia');
    console.error(error);
}

// prints:
// start
// inside
// nvmnghia
// TypeError: set props of null

try {
    console.log('start')
    const test = (async () => { // Note the async without await
        console.log('inside')
        const a = null;
        a.c = 1
    })()
    console.log('end')
} catch (error) {
    console.log('nvmnghia');
    console.error(error);
}

// prints:
// start
// inside
// end
// undefined, due to normal return
// Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ...
//   and no nvmnghia, which means the error wasn't caught indeed

Why does it behave this way? I'm surpise cuz my mental model for async/promise has always been that the part before the first await is run synchronously i.e. NOT scheduled in a microtask.

"my mental model for async/promise has always been that the part before the first await is run synchronously" - well it does, that's why "inside" is logged before "end". Now what is unexpected about the output?

@Bergi the unexpected thing is that the error is not caught in the outer event handler. I didn't aware that promise also catches error in this part.

Yes, the exception is caught anywhere, code would be very fragile otherwise (if introducing/removing await changes how throw behaves elsewhere in the function). The idea is that an async function should never throw a synchronous exception, it should always return a promise (and may reject it), so that you don't have to handle some errors with try/catch and other errors with promise .catch().

When your code is run synchronously, the errors get caught immediately by try/catch. When it is async, even if there is no await used, the function returns a promise, and errors are then instead handled by the error of the promise. These errors don't get caught by a try/catch, so you'll need to use .catch() or await.

so it returns promise immediately, and still execute the "inside" line first, instead of going straight to the "end" line?

@MinhNghĩa Yes that is correct.

JS engine handles asynchronous request in form of events. So, catch block can't handle async error. You can handle that error in promise catch like below:
try {
    console.log('start')
    const test = (async () => { // Note the async without await
        console.log('inside')
        const a = null;
        a.c = 1
    })().catch(err => console.log("Catch from promise block:", err));
    console.log('end')
} catch (error) {
    console.log('nvmnghia');
    console.error(error);
}

You will see Catch from promise block:  in output before error.

In fact it can, just await the expression.

if you are using await then it can
